# jQuery UI Datepicker: Align below label issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

http://jsfiddle.net/r7D2x/

I'm trying to use jQuery Datepicker on a label (`<span>`) instead of an input field. Here's the code:

```
// javascript 
$('#placeholder').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showMonthAfterYear: true,
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: 'set',
    dateFormat: 'd-M-y',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var epoch = date.valueOf() / 1000;
        $('#value').val(epoch);
        $('#label').text(dateText);
    }
});
(function() {
    var initial = 1297800000;
    var $label = $('#label');
    if (initial == '' || initial == '0') {
        $label.text('not set');
    } else {
        var date = new Date(initial * 1000);
        $label.text($.datepicker.formatDate('d-M-y', date));
    }

})();

<!-- html -->
<span id="label" /><:input_nulldate></span>
<input type="hidden" id="placeholder" />
<input type="hidden" id="value"  />
```

But I can't get it to popup under the `<span>`. It keeps popping up over the button instead. How can I get it to align correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the box around using css.  For instance:

```
.ui-datepicker { 
  margin-left: -80px;
  margin-top: 40px

}
```

Will get it about where you want it.

Comment: heh. those numbers were bang on. was hoping there was some kind of positioning option to anchor it to a different element..this is kind of contingent on things staying the same size. but oh well

Comment: Another option that might work is attaching the datepicker to a div or span but not have it show via button in the config. The documentation has examples of these static datepickera. Then you could make your own button that calls the show and hide on the datepicker.